# Block skype using iptables

Tags: security, firewall, iptables, skype

Any way to block skype from our network using IPTABLES ?

Comment: Find out what port it's running on by installing it on a machine you control and running wireshark.

Comment: it seems skype application uses ports dynamically scanning which are not blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype is P2P-like, it's very difficult to block it using only iptables.
You should checkout layer7 (http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/protocols)